# Deciphering romanized Korean: "kama/kamuh toe olgami"

Tags: vocabulary, translation, romanisation

In my martial arts book, "The Art of Kyuki-Do", it describes a particular maneuver (called in English, "middle section corkscrew trap, in to out") as variously "kama toe olgami" and "kamuh toe olgami". I understand "olgami" as 올가미, "trap", and "kama/kamuh" might be 감아, from 감다 (which the Prime Korean/English dictionary defines as "wind (up); roll (up); tie, ...". But toe...I can't decide if it's supposed to be two syllables (도에, 토에, etc.) or one (도, 토, 퇴, etc.). I can't find any word that seems appropriate here.

If it helps, the maneuver being described is one in which you move your arm in a large circle, wrapping it (corkscrew-style) around your opponent's arm, trapping them. (Sadly, I can't find the maneuver described or demonstrated anywhere online, or I'd post a link to clarify further.)

I'd love to know how this phrase is actually supposed to be rendered in Korean. Thank you!

Comment: toe might be 더, as in the 서 in Seoul is written as Seo, 감아 더 올감이, wrap up and snare in a stronger trap perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Might be the prefix "되-" (pronounced somewhat like "dweh").  It's not a word in itself, but means "again" or "re-".  E.g., 되풀이 repetition, 되감다 rewind, 되돌림 undo (from "turn again"), etc.

되- is usually attached to a verb (or a noun made from a verb), so attaching it to 올가미 (a specific kind of trap) sounds a bit strange to me, but I guess that's not impossible when you're making up new terms for a martial art move.